# Do 16 bit register pairs make a machine 16 bit?

Tags: assembly, machine-instruction, vm-implementation

I have been working on a fictional retro virtual machine for xbox since January (I am not at all copying 0x10c, infact my project is older. just putting this out there incase some notch fanboys read this) and it has 6 general purpose registers. These are 8 bit but all can be combined to make 3 16 bit registers, memory addresses though are 16 bit and so is the program counter. I know this is a stupid question, but I couldn't figure this out, is it 16 or 8 bit???? The z80 uses 16 bit addresses and is 8 bit

Comment: You have to consider the adress bus and a databus of old processors. The address bus gives the information how much memory is accessible (for the address bus this is not true in any case, but in most) and the data bus define the maximum number which can be stored in an accumulator register. The bit width of a processor is mainly defined by its data bus size and not by its address bus size.

Comment: generally it is whatever marketing describes it as, it doesnt have to mean anything relevant.  usually it has to do with the size of your registers and or operations.  Can you only do 8 bit alu operations? (call it 8 bit) can you combine registers and do 16 bit operations? (call it 16 bit).  How much it can address is a separate topic and not always related to the register size.  most 8 bit processors can address more than 256 bytes and many 16 bit can address more than 65536 bytes.

Comment: There is no real answer -- no universally accepted definition of what constitutes an N-bit machine. The Z80 not only uses 16-bit addresses, but also has register pairs like you've described (BC, DE, and HL) and as well as IX and IY, with some 16-bit instructions to operate on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know and learned of, the processor's bit width of the general purpose register determines  it, because all the calculations are rely on the clock speed, and it can do process only the amount of the general purpose register.

For example, in a 32-bit processor, it can do 64 bit calculations by register concatenation, but it doesn't possible to call it as a 64-bit processor. Of course there are some 64-bit extensive instructions in 32-bit processors, but they consumes double clocks, two steps.

I think your processor's designer just want to expand the memory address space to support more big memory.

So, my conclusion is 8-bit processor.

Answer (score 0):

Can your processor process 16 bits of data in one go, or does it use two separate 8 bit operations behind the scenes? If the former, it's 16 bit. If the latter, it's 8 bit.

From your description, it sounds like 16 bit, since it uses 16 bits for data addressing.

Answer (score -1):

The most common definition of what constitutes a 16-bit processor is the size of the longest integer type that can be handled by the processor with native instructions. If your virtual machine has arithmetic instructions that operate on the 16-bit registers and give 16-bit inputs, it qualifies as a 16-bit machine.

Another common definition is the size of the address space. Since your virtual machine has 16-bit addresses, it would also qualify as 16-bit.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought, but what confused me and made me ask this is the z80 which is 8 bit but used 16 bit addressing

Comment: the 6502 and its ilk were 8 bit processors with 16 bit address rdgisters.  it was most definitely an 8 bit cpu.

Comment: Edited, I only recalled that 8-bit CPUs had 16-bit addresses after I wrote this.

Comment: The original IBM PC had an 8088 processor with a 20 bit address bus and an 8 bit data bus. Still considered a 16-bit processor.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Yes you are right. As far as I know this was for cost reasons. At the end the 16 bit databus was implemented by multiplexing the 8 bit databus. The result was a very slow processor at a low price but opcode compatible to the real 16 bit 8086.